# How can I use async function in hardwareBackPress listener?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I made an application that can make agora voice calls with React native. When clicking `leave` on the screen, the below agoraEnd function works correctly. I also want this function to work when the phone's back button is pressed. That's why I prepared the useFocusEffet below. But when I press the back button during a voice call, I get the following error. Why is this function not working correctly? How can I fix this problem.

`Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 2): TypeError: engine.leaveChannel is not a function. (In 'engine.leaveChannel()', 'engine.leaveChannel' is undefined)`

```js
  const agoraEnd = async () => {
    await engine.leaveChannel()
    await engine.destroy()
    navigation.goBack();
  };

  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
        'hardwareBackPress',
        agoraEnd,
      );
      return () => backHandler.remove();
    }, []),
  )
```

Comment: can you try doing async () => await agoraEnd() ?

Comment: @RamaProg yes i tried but i got the same error

Comment: can you provide all the code? where is engine coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you don't return anything from back handler (though it expects boolean, where `true` when you handled back press and `false` when you didn't and want to continue default behaviour (usually exiting the app))

You can just do:

```js
  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
        'hardwareBackPress',
        () => agoraEnd(),
      );
      return () => backHandler.remove();
    }, []),
  )
```

if you don't want to wait for agoraEnd to finish.

---

So **in my case** I used `BackHandler.exitApp();` to do async stuff:

```js
  const handleBackButtonAsync = async () => {
     // do some await stuff

     if (something) {
        // the back button event is handled;
     } else {
       // THE MAGIC:
       // instead of returning `false` in `handleBackButton`
       // to not prevent default logic, you exit app explicitly
       BackHandler.exitApp(); 
     }
  }
  const handleBackButton = () => {
    handleBackButtonAsync();
    return true; // always "handle" the back button event to not exit app
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", handleBackButton);

    return () =>
      BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", handleBackButton);
  }, []);
```